# Using Spring Data LDAP with openjdk

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-ldap

I have a `Spring Boot 2.0.6` application with `spring-data-ldap 2.0.9.RELEASE` as a dependency, and I am having a problem retrieving all the distinguishedNames from an Active Directory tree. This problem occurs while using `openjdk-9.0.4` and `openjdk-10.0.2`. I get the following stack trace:

```
2019-02-05 11:57:31,037 ERROR [Management-Server] [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] LdapService: Problem Querying Ldap to get the OU tree: {}
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx cannot be cast to org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$34.mapFromContext(LdapTemplate.java:1843) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextMapperCallbackHandler.getObjectFromNameClassPair(ContextMapperCallbackHandler.java:69) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.CollectingNameClassPairCallbackHandler.handleNameClassPair(CollectingNameClassPairCallbackHandler.java:50) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:367) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:642) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:578) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1840) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1861) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:223) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:494) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30b3b8ad.find(<generated>) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.support.SimpleLdapRepository.findAll(SimpleLdapRepository.java:149) ~[spring-data-ldap-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.compapp.server.service.ldap.LdapService.collectAllOUInLdap(LdapService.java:159) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.compapp.server.service.ldap.LdapService.retrieveLdapTreeAsJsonObject(LdapService.java:68) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.compapp.server.service.ldap.LdapService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d05a21c0.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.compapp.server.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:47) ~[classes!/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor376.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.compapp.server.service.ldap.LdapService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$40367ff1.retrieveLdapTreeAsJsonObject(<generated>) ~[classes!/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1603) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175) ~[?:?]
2019-02-05 11:57:31,041 ERROR [Management-Server] [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] LoggingAspect: Exception in com.compapp.server.service.ldap.LdapService.retrieveLdapTreeAsJsonObject() with cause = null
```

I went over the official Spring Boot 2.0.6 documentation and in the System Requirements section it states:

> **9. System Requirements**
>
> Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE requires Java 8 or 9 and Spring Framework
>   5.0.10.RELEASE or above.

However this error doesn't occur if I use `Java 1.8.0_181`. Is there some compatibility issue with open-jdk that I am not aware of?

Appreciate the help.